# Coded ui test data format wrong only when running on a test agent

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and have a data driven coded ui test that uses a csv file.  The csv file and schema.ini file are both checked in.  When I run the test locally the test runs without a problem.  When I run the test through Test Manager which sends it to a test agent the test fails because it tries to enter data into a field as 222197120000 instead of 1971-02-22.

The data in the csv file is 1971-02-22.

The coded ui test has the following:

[DeploymentItem("Applicant.csv")]

[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\Applicant.csv", "Applicant#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]